# triggering another object with same class to fadeout with timer

Tags: jquery, fadein

so i've been trying to make this work now for some time. I'm quite new to jquery as you guys might tell.

Q:How do I make each of these divs fade in at different timestamps?

JSfiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/vzLbgtfx/1/`

HTML:

```
<div class="betin">a</div>
<div class="betin">b</div>
<div class="betin">c</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.betin:eq(0)').fadeIn('slow',1000),
    $('.betin:eq(1)').fadeIn('slow',2000),
    $('.betin:eq(2)').fadeIn('slow',3000);


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var delay = 1000;

    $('.betin').each(function(){
        var $el = $(this);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $el.fadeIn('slow');
        }, delay);

        delay += 1000;
    });

});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/voveson/vzLbgtfx/3/